# Using P7B certificate for client authentication

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, client-certificates, mutual-authentication

We are integrating with a service provider and we are clients consuming their service. We have a requirement to use mutual authentication (2-way SSL). I have PKCS#7 file and imported the .p7b file into my chrome browser. I could not get the SSL handshake work successfully from my browser. Any pointers on testing from browser using P7B file?

Note: We have the java client working with JKS and I could test with a P12 file from the browser. The reason I want to test with P7B file is because we don't want to share P12 file with the service provider.

Comment: For authenticating with a client certificate you need the certificate and the private key. AFAIR a `.p7b` file does contain the cert but not the private key, therefore it will not work as you already have noticed. Import `.p12` file into chrome and it will (most likely) work if the file contains the client certificate and the private key. BTW: What do you mean with *we don't want to share .p12 file with the service provider.*?

Comment: @Robert The connection does work with .p12. When I said we don't want to share, that is to avoid sharing the private keys with them as p12 contains private key.

Comment: @Robert. Let me know if there is a way for the service provider to test from their browser without sharing the private key.

Comment: Hopefully you don't use the .p12 file used as SSL certificate on the server? The client certificates (and keys) have to generated individually, one for each user. If you do so sharing is not a problem anymore. Remember no private key means no authentication with client certificate...

Comment: the client cert I am talking here, is a CSR generated from our end and signed by the service provider with their CA. SO i am not following your comment (`Hopefully you don't use the .p12 file used as SSL certificate on the server and Remember no private key means no authentication with client certificate`).